# Where to find E.coli gene expression data?

Tags: bioinformatics, gene-expression, rna-sequencing, ecoli

I am searching *E.coli* whole genome expression data with different conditions, any suggestion is appreciated. Condition could be for example different growth temperature, different medias, etc. 
I have tried GEO but it only gives a list and one should read all pages and samples one by one to see which conditions were used.

Comment: What do you mean with "different condition"? GEO is a database which holds gene expression data, so it is not the place to look for whole genomes. If you look for gene expression data instead, please adapt your question. Information about different complete *E.coli* genomes can be found [here](http://ecoliwiki.net/colipedia/index.php/Sequenced_E._coli_Genomes)

Comment: @Chris  I modified my question

Comment: Are you looking for something that would give you a list of what genes are expressed under specific conditions?

Comment: you can run an automated GEO query and fetch GEO accession numbers for the ones that match your keywords.

Comment: If you are interested in sequencing data then search NCBI-SRA

Comment: @WYSIWYG can you please give me an example how to run it and how to get them?

Comment: @Nemo see [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25500/). You have to construct a search based on your keywords and mention the database. Then you have to mine the retrieved list of information to select which ones you actually require. You can then download the data corresponding to these experiments in a similar manner. See [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/info/geo_paccess.html#ExampleII) too. If you have specific doubts about this then post them as new questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some databases in which you can search for *E.coli* gene expression data:

- [GenExpDB](http://genexpdb.ou.edu/main/): *E. coli* Gene Expression Database
- [Many Microbe Microarrays Database (M3D)](http://m3d.mssm.edu/): A resource of microbial
  gene expression data
- [Stanford MicroArray Database](http://smd.princeton.edu/index.shtml) (use the search tool to find relevant organisms)
- [Colombos](http://www.colombos.net/) (COLlection Of Microarrays for Bacterial OrganismS)
- [ArrayExpress](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/arrayexpress/)

To find out about the purpose and the conditions of the experiments behind this data sets you will have to read the respective publications.

Comment: can you please post some example papers done for E coli gene expression data if you are aware  of any

Comment: @Nemo http://lmgtfy.com/?q=e.coli+gene+expression+studies